# Android Studio and Eclipse ADT on Windows 10?

Tags: eclipse, windows, android-studio, compatibility

**Good day!

I am an IT student that is currently working on my Android app project and my laptop frequently notify me whenever I open to upgrade to Windows 10, (I am a genuine Windows 8.1 user installe on my Dell Vostro 5460).

Now, my question, is Android Studio and Eclipse ADT compatible with Windows 10? It is because I want the Windows 10 experience, but I have doubt that it will not be compatible with Android Studio and Eclipse ADT. Please help me with my question. Thanks you very much.**

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio had I installed on the Windows 10 Technical Preview and it works. I could it open and develop a new Project.(I don't know what happend with a old project, but i think it must be work also.)

For a Tutorial how you install Ecplise i found this:

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55390/how-do-i-install-eclipse-and-java-sdk-into-windows-10

Is it this what you mean?